# How to Clear ComboBox items in SelectionChanged Event of another combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

i have two ComboBoxes in WPF Application...

in first ComboBox SelectionChanged Event i want to clear Second CombBox items....

```
private void cmbBoard_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    cmbClass.DataContext = this;
    cmbClass.Items.Clear();

    CVariables.StrSQLQueryPub = "select ClassID,Class from QB_Class WHERE BoardID='" + strBoardId + "' ORDER BY Class";
    CFunctions.fnToFillDataTable(CFunctions.Con, CVariables.StrSQLQueryPub);
    DataTable dt = CVariables.DTable;

    cmbClass.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    cmbClass.DisplayMemberPath = "Class";
    cmbClass.SelectedValuePath = "ClassID";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply just call the `Clear()` method on `Items` property of the `ComboBox`.

```
cmbClass.Items.Clear();
```

You are doing it right in your piece of code but later you are also populating it with `dt.DefaultView`. So this way you might not be having the expected outcome.

Comment: Please tell me what to use instead of dt.DefaultView.

Comment: I want Clear Items of 2nd ComboBox while filling it in 1st Combobox SelectioChanges event

Answer (score 0):

Just give this code

```
   comboBox1.Items.Clear()
```